# How to translate correct these two sentences?

Tags: translation, grammar, meaning

刚来一会儿。 «I came here just for a while». Or in a while?

他刚到十分钟。 he came just for 10 minutes or he will arrive just in ten minutes??

Please correct me,thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

刚来一会: (I)'ve only been here for a bit since (my) arrival

他刚到十分钟: It has only been 10 minutes since his arrival.

If 刚 combines with a verb, the action is already performed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @user25207 Hi, since no one else has made another answer so far, if you are satisfied with my answer, would you mind accepting it as the answer to the question? Thanks.